# Spring Boot 3 - How do I get permitAll() to work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot 3. I am trying to permit all requests to a particular endpoint. I have the user's details in a mysql table (users), where I store the username, password and the role. The password is encrypted using Bcrypt. I used https://bcrypt-generator.com/ to generate the encrypted code and stored it in the database. Here's the sample password from the table - {bcrypt}$2a$12$2mERuojKpXO8N2qX2OXmBOAIuVM6pSImxlcrrJXHNyI3iowgHe5Zi

Here's the code

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RestSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests( configurer -> 
            configurer
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/**").permitAll()
        );
        
        // use HTTP Basic Authentication
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        // disable Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource dataSource){
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, password, enabled from users where username=?"
        );
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, role from users where username=?"
        );

        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to access this endpoint, I get a 401 Unauthorized. It seems like permitAll() is not working. It still requires me to provide the login credentials. How do I fix this?

Another thing I wanted to know was, how do I send the encrypted password for authentication on Postman?

Edit 1:

Here are the logs -

```
2023-12-21T17:01:31.411+05:30  WARN 22830 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2023-12-21T17:01:31.411+05:30 DEBUG 22830 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
2023-12-21T17:01:31.412+05:30 DEBUG 22830 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Failed to process authentication request
```

Comment: What URL do you call? Show your request with headers. Also show more of your logs, not only 3 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication is not authorization. `permitAll` is part of authorization and applies *after* authentication. Yes, authentication *may* leave the request without credentials anonymous which `permitAll` then accepts. But not when authentication process itself encounters an exception processing credentials, which is your case - your credentials are malformed. So, 401 happens because authentication process detects that request has credentials but still cannot make a decision. And yes, it is intended behavior.

The solution is to fix credentials processing. And based on the example token you provided (`{bcrypt}....`) you should use delegating encoder. The difference is that `BCryptPasswordEncoder` handles tokens of only one type and does not expect any prefix, whereas `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` can handle tokens of various types and requires prefix to distinguish between them. There is a convinient method to construct such an encoder with reasonable set of possible prefixes:

```
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt)
you must use passwordEncoder of spring boot like this :

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public User registerNewUserAccount(UserDto accountDto) throws EmailExistsException {

    User user = new User();
    
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));

    return repository.save(user);
}
```

based on your log you need change your bcrypt password and regenerated password with
this method like:

```
passwordEncoder.encode("123456789")
```

and set it on database